# Apache SPARK with SQLContext:: IndexError

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute a basic example provided in **Inferring the Schema Using Reflection** segment of Apache SPARK documentation.

I'm doing this on Cloudera Quickstart VM(CDH5)

The example I'm trying to execute is as below ::

```
# sc is an existing SparkContext.
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# Load a text file and convert each line to a Row.
lines = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/analytics/book6_sample.csv")
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
people = parts.map(lambda p: Row(name=p[0], age=int(p[1])))

# Infer the schema, and register the DataFrame as a table.
schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people)
schemaPeople.registerTempTable("people")

# SQL can be run over DataFrames that have been registered as a table.
teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")

# The results of SQL queries are RDDs and support all the normal RDD operations.
teenNames = teenagers.map(lambda p: "Name: " + p.name)
for teenName in teenNames.collect():
  print(teenName)
```

I ran the code exactly as shown as above but always getting the error "**IndexError: list index out of range**"  when I execute the last command(the for loop).

The input file book6_sample is available at
[book6_sample.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7NgTayxCMOTcDNQUF9nRmFTM2M).

I ran the code exactly as shown as above but always getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range"  when I execute the last command(the for loop).

Please suggest pointers on where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file has one empty line at the end which is causing this error.Open your file in text editor and remove that line hope it will work

Comment: Hey sachin,That did work after making the suggested change.Thank you